# ImportError: Django Cities

Tags: django, importerror

I'm wondering why I am getting an `ImportError` when using [django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities).

```
from cities.models import PostalCode
```

I have already synced db and `cities` tables exist in the database. The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/lib/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/lib/python2.7/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/lib/python2.7/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError haystack: cannot import name PostalCode
```

The ImportError suggests that python is looking for `PostalCode` in `haystack`, but I am asking it to import from `cities`.. Why does this happen? Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Although both the github and pypi versions claim to be 0.2, it turns out that they are different. I installed via pip, and the pypi version does not have a `PostalCode` model class, which was the source of my `ImportError`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more likely to be in your models.py somewhere. You could have circular import (in other words, a case where A imports from B and B imports from A).

Comment: No, I dont think that is the issue because this line `from cities.models import PostalCode` is the only line that breaks the code. Everything else works fine. Thanks for any further ideas.